# how to retrieve select option ids and values via the web api

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using the `api/data/v8.0` API endpoint of a microsoft crm 2016 and I can retrieve and update a specific entity using `GET` and `PATCH` on `api/data/v8.0/accounts(063e4c86-e7f0-e511-93f7-123456bb6ce7)`.

That entity has a property called `jobtypecode` (I can see that on the JSON response of the `GET`) and on the front end of the CRM the possible values are the following (I retrieved them using dev tools by inspecting that html select):

```
721874717   Full Time
721874719   Part Time
721874713   Academic
721874714   Other
```

How can I retrieve those values via the API?

I tried using `api/data/v8.0/GlobalOptionSetDefinitions` and various combinations of `api/data/v8.0/EntityDefinitions` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EntityDefinitions with the MetadataId of account, add a filter to only get the optionset you want.

```
EntityDefinitions(70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84)/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet,GlobalOptionSet
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx#bkmk_queryAttributes